# subspace verificaion

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

if W is a subspace of a vector space V, show that for all vectors x1, x2,...xn in W, and all scalats a1, a2, ...an in R, the vector a1x1 + a2x2+...+anxn is in W

Here are my steps.

Since W is a subspace, this means already that any sum of vectors from W is a vector in W,

As well any sclar multiplication of a vector from W is a vecto from W.

Therefore the sum stated above is also a vector in W

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. It's just that you have to formalize it properly and state things in the proper order.

Say you have vectors $x_1, ..., x_n$ in $W$ and scalars $a_1, ..., a_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since a scalar multiple of any vector in $W$ is also in $W$, you have for any $x_i$ that $a_ix_i$ is in $W$.

Since $a_ix_i$ is in $W$ for all $i=1,...,n$, and the sum of any vectors in $W$ is also in $W$, then $a_1x_1 + ... + a_nx_n$ is also in $W$.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i'm typing on a tablet so that wws my condensed version